# Is it possible to connect a Linux Raspberry Pi 3 to USB tethering and Wifi Internet at the same time?

Tags: linux, usb, wifi-configuration, tethering

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 and I would like to USB tether to it from my phone while simultaneously connect to the Internet over Wi-Fi from the Raspberry Pi. I am guessing that I need to change the settings in `dhcpcd.conf`, `/network/interfaces` and/or `wpa_supplicant.conf` but I am not sure about how. I used to do something similar using Windows a long time ago so it's probably possible on Linux as well somehow.

Anyone knows exactly what the settings should be like? I don't want to lock myself out of the Raspberry Pi by accident because there is no laptop nearby to edit the configuration files if I get locked out.

Comment: You can connect to both, but note you won't be able to use "the internet" via both at the same time (aka having a default route to both). This is a FAQ, and gets asked in various variants about every week or so; see those questions for details. What **purpose** should connecting the RaspPi to two different ISPs serve? (Please edit the question, don't reply as a comment).